# Error in window.default(x, ...) : 'start' cannot be after 'end' during cross-validation of VAR model in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, forecast

I have a dataframe with differenced data.

Data has format `[1] "mts" "ts" "matrix"`(tried `"mts" "ts"` too).

Data goes from March 2008 to August 2020 (150 values in total).

The sample `dput` of `chicago_diff11` dataframe is the following:

```
structure(c(-4000, 3000, 1000, 5000, 3500, -3500, 0.0499999999999998, 
-0.0499999999999998, 0.12, 0.28, 0.109999999999999, 0.0500000000000007
), .Dim = c(6L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Median_price_ts_diff1", 
"Average_rate_ts_diff1")), .Tsp = c(2008.16666666667, 2008.58333333333, 
12), class = c("mts", "ts", "matrix"))
```

I am trying to replicate the code from [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/200598/forecasting-methodology-and-k-fold-cross-validation-for-a-vector-autoregression).

My current code looks like

```
# Forecast horizon
j <- 12

# Length of minimum training set
k <- nrow(chicago_diff11) - j 

# Create actual and prediction
prediction <- data.frame()
actual <- data.frame()

for (i in j) { 
  trainingset <- window(chicago_diff11, end = k+i-1)
  testset <- window(chicago_diff11, start = k-j+i+1, end = k+j)
  fit <- VAR(trainingset, p = 10)                       
  fcast <- forecast(fit, h = j)
  fcastmean <- do.call('cbind', fcast[['mean']])
  fcastmean <- as.data.frame(fcastmean)

  prediction <- rbind(prediction, fcastmean)
  actual <- rbind(actual, as.data.frame(testset[,1]))
}

# add predictions and actual values
result <- cbind(prediction, actual[, 1])
names(result) <- c("Predicted", "Actual")
result$Difference <- abs(result$Actual - result$Predicted)

# Use Mean Absolute Error as Evalution 
summary(result$Difference)
```

But this function breaks

`Error in window.default(x, ...) : 'start' cannot be after 'end'`

My data structure is the same as in the original question. What and where am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: your probably intended `i in 1:j` in the for loop.

Comment: @Suren, unfortunately error remains the same :(

Comment: That's wasn't fix the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specification of end/start of `window` function is wrong. See an example below.

```
window(chicago_diff11, end = c(2008, 7))
```

> ```
>          Median_price_ts_diff1 Average_rate_ts_diff1
> Mar 2008                 -4000                  0.05
> Apr 2008                  3000                 -0.05
> May 2008                  1000                  0.12
> Jun 2008                  5000                  0.28
> Jul 2008                  3500                  0.11
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort! Any tips how to update the function to make it work? Thanks!

Comment: Instead of having k + i - j in `end`,  you have to find year and month for the window.

Comment: or `trainingset = chicago_diff11[1:(k + i - j), ]` might work.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately, I changed the training set, using your code. Maybe I need to do something for the test set too.

Comment: I would greatly appreciate your help here

Comment: cheers. I think the question you have must be answered from the above.